# TYPO3 newsslider for news system extension 4.0.0

Tags: typo3, tx-news

Is there a way to have [newsslider extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/newsslider) working with the latest tx_news(news system) 4.0.0 on a fresh installed typo3 7.6.0 besides digging into code? The extension installation warning says that it requires a manual intervention? The page where the plugin is inserted gives Fatal error: Call to a member function wrapClickMenuOnIcon() on null in typo3conf/ext/newsslider/Classes/Hooks/PageLayoutView.php on line 252   viewed in backend.

What is the solution for having any kind of a newsslider with above typo3 version and news system version?

Comment: You can always write the template yourself. After all the extension does little more than providing a html rendering (via a custom news template) and some preconfigured Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written already in the comment, the best way is to use a templateLayout.

Add the following into the **Page TsConfig**:

```
tx_news.templateLayouts {
       10 = Slider
}
```

And then you can select the entry "Slider" in the plugin. Inside the template, you can now check `{settings.templateLayout}` by using a `<f:if>`and change the markup you need for the slider.

The great advantages using this way are:

- No additional dependencies to another extension
- Use the jquery or any JS library which fits best